# Javascript variable scoping issue

Tags: javascript, scope, object-literal

I'm having a problem referencing a global variable inside an object literal:

```
function f() {
    globalVar = "test";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    f();
    var a = $("#id").autocomplete({ 
        lookup: globalVar //says globalVar is undefined
    });
    $("#button").click(function() {
        alert(globalVar); //works
    });
});
```

How can I set the value of `lookup` to globalVar?

Comment: Is this your actual code? There's no reason `globalVar` would be defined in the `alert()`, but undefined for the property value assignment.

Comment: What browser(s) did you test in?

Comment: @patrick You're right, the alert is actually in a click event as shown. The alert did not work how I had it, but it definitely works as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason that shouldn't work, it either has to do with a misunderstanding on how to use that autocomplete function, or a problem in the function itself. But the global should be assigned, and there is no problem assigning a global to an object that way. Either way, without more code (i.e. that autocomplete function), can't say what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

you can define it outside all functions like this;

```
var globalVar ;

function f() {
    globalVar = "test";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    f();
    alert(globalVar); //works
    var a = $("#id").autocomplete({ 
        lookup: globalVar 
    });
});
```